# How to convert Array of columns to rows in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column as below screenshot in my google bigquery

[image]

i need to convert that column to rows as below in Bigquery :

70042
70055
70044
70046
70042
70055
70044
70046

Please suggest me how can i get the rows like above.

Comment: welcome to SO, please show what you done so far, So other can help you better

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Below examples for BigQuery Standard SQL
First is applicable if your column is an array of string and second in case if it is a string that looks like array :o)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ['70042', '70055', '70044', '70046'] dspid UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, ['70042', '70055', '70044', '70046'] dspid 
)
SELECT id, dspid
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(dspid) dspid   


#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '["70042","70055","70044","70046"]' dspid UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, '["70042","70055","70044","70046"]' dspid 
)
SELECT id, dspid
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(dspid, r'[\[\]"]', ''))) dspid
```

Both produce below result

```
Row id  dspid    
1   1   70042    
2   1   70055    
3   1   70044    
4   1   70046    
5   2   70042    
6   2   70055    
7   2   70044    
8   2   70046
```

Note: below fragment is used just to mimic you real data / table and just for you to test / play with.  In reality, you can remove it and use your specific `project.dataset.table`

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  ..............
)
```

Next time you ask question on SO please provide more details about your case and show what you tried even if it didn't work for you  - this usually helps us to better understand your case and thus better help you

> Update

So, for example, if your table is `veuhub-185502.AdtechAnalytics.tag_request` you should use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, dspid
FROM `veuhub-185502.AdtechAnalytics.tag_request`,
UNNEST(dspid) dspid
```

or below for (based on your comments)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  DSPID, 
  adtype, 
  adtypeWithDevice, 
  EXTRACT(year FROM request_timestamp) AS year, 
  EXTRACT(month FROM request_timestamp) AS month, 
  EXTRACT(day FROM request_timestamp) AS day, 
  EXTRACT(hour FROM request_timestamp) AS hour, 
  SUM(1) AS requestcount 
FROM `veuhub-185502.AdtechAnalytics.tag_request`, 
UNNEST(dspid) dspid 
GROUP BY adtype,adTypeWithDevice,DSPID,year,month,day,hour
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually i was trying to ask you the clarification in the previous comment. I am trying to use your query, it can work alone with that DSPID column however, the select statement wont allow the other columns of the table. i am getting the error like Unrecognized name: adtype at [5:15]

Comment: WITH `veuhub-185502.AdtechAnalytics.tag_request` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ['70042', '70055', '70044', '70046'] dspid UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, ['70042', '70055', '70044', '70046'] dspid 
)
SELECT DSPID, adtype, adtypeWithDevice,
Extract(year from request_timestamp) as year,
Extract(month from request_timestamp) as month,
Extract(day from request_timestamp) as day,
Extract(hour from request_timestamp) as hour,
sum(1) as requestcount
FROM `veuhub-185502.AdtechAnalytics.tag_request`,
UNNEST(dspid) dspid  
group by adtype,adTypeWithDevice,DSPID,year,month,day,hour

Comment: I am using the query as above. Getting the error as below : Unrecognized name: adtype at [5:15]

Comment: And also it wont work for all the rows of DSPID, only working for selected ones

Comment: Please give me some suggestions

Comment: In my table dspid is string type as we dont have any types to store that kind of data. hence, i am getting the error as below. how we can handle the array types in bigquery ?                                                                                                                    error :   Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRING at [11:8]

Comment: As i am new to bigquery and also fresher too hence i got confused. Now its working fine. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Sure. No problem :o). Come back with new questions when have ones